# Detaching Rhino.Commons from a project

Tags: .net, nhibernate, castle-activerecord, rhino-commons

I have a project which uses Rhino.ActiveRecord's ARRepository, unfortunatly the project is no longer maintained and both of NHibernate's and ActiveRecord's versions are very old and we really need to upgrade.
How do I detach the dependency from my project while still maintaing the same API of ARRepository?
It seems that ARRepository is too tightly coupled to the rest of the library so what can I do?

Comment: What (concretely) do you find it's missing? Why not implement it and submit it to the project?

Comment: I need to upgrade ActiveRecord, NHibernate and Windsor to solve the bugs I'm having, it's too much work to do on the original library which is no longer maintained.

Comment: ARRepository is really not complex. You can always ask for directions on the Rhino mailing list. http://groups.google.com/group/rhino-tools-dev

Comment: BTW this is really how open source works. You find a project that you need, you use it, after a while you find it's missing something so you implement it and contribute it to the project. When lots of people do this, the project moves forward and everyone benefits. If you are just a user and don't contribute back when you find it's missing something, everyone loses. Including you.

Comment: @Mauricio Scheffer: I am fully aware of that, it's not my decsion to make. Tell that to my boss.

Comment: @the_drow: I apologize for my patronizing attitude, I know sometimes it's hard to contribute.

Comment: @Mauricio Scheffer: It's ok, it's a nightmare of project to work with anyway so I get you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have [you checked the project's forks](http://github.com/lorenzomelato/rhino-commons/network) on Github?

This one for instance has http://github.com/janlimpens/rhino-commons/commits/master NHibernate 3.0 Alpha 2 and Windsor 2.1